# azure pipeline deployment for Cloud services (classic) web app

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to get a deployment working from Azure Pipelines and cannot figure out how to deploy a single "Cloud Service classic hosted" web app.  I am not finding much documentation about how to configure my template beyond the basic canned templates Azure offers.  Does anyone know of better documentation or an example template to deploy from a build?  Previously I was deploying directly from Visual Studio running locally, so this jump to using Pipelines is a big one for me.